# Searching through objects, client-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have 50-100 objects in memory client-side. I need to search them without tags, just text searching every field of the object and finding matches or partial matches.

What is the best way to do this type of search, how can I list them based on relevance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elements:**

If you want to look for text within elements, try this:

```
$(":contains('your text')");
```

This will return each element that contains `your text`.

**Objects**

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/datyn/1/

Also searches for sub objects, currently searches Case Insensitive, if you want to change it, just remove the `.toLowerCase()` functions:

```
var ob = {
    User : {
        name : "Niels",
        country : "Netherlands"
    },
    Name : "Niels test X"
}

function find_match(search, results)
{
    $.each(this, function(k, v){
       if( typeof(v) == "object" )
       {
            find_match.call(v, search, results);  
       }
        else
        {
             if( v.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) != -1)
             {
                 if($.inArray(this, results) == -1)
                 {
                     results.push(this);
                 }   
             }
        }
    });
}

var results = [];
find_match.call(ob, "x", results);
alert("Search for x results: " + results.length);
var results = [];
find_match.call(ob, "n", results);
alert("Search for n results: " + results.length);
```

You can call the function by using `.call` method.

Example :

```
find_match.call("Object / array you want to search", "The string", "Array where the results will be stored")
```

Changes:

1. If you don't want to match a part of a string, change: `v.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) != -1` into `v.toLowerCase() == search.toLowerCase()`

Comment: I guess just searching text values would be fine and searching into sub-objects would be ideal.

Comment: Ah, very nice, and basic relevance would be based on the amt of times it was found? I'm guessing there are probably better, more complex ways to create relevance, like exact word match is worth more then a partial match, but this is a great start. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to have specific match, you can change the `indexOf` to `if(v.toLowerCase() == search.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Awesome, I will use this. Know of any research, or a lib that could push more logic into the equation? a, the, is, matches don't mean as much, other quirks, how to weight what, etc?

Comment: It currently does not split your search string into different possible matches, if you got the string `My name is`, it will find a match that contains the string `My name is`, not looking for each word.

Comment: Ok, I can slice it and run the function for each -- but then words found in order should be worth more too. Hah this is endless.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this:

http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Answer (score 0):

For each object in your collection (with 50-100 I assume they are kept in an array perhaps, or the result of a jQuery selection), use `Object.keys` to get the property names then grab the associated value and perform your match.

Since your match returns a relevance score, you can place all matches into an array of pairs (match x score) and do an array sort with a comparator set to compare by score.

Comment: Sounds like this is in the right direction. How do I preform my 'match' though, and how does it return a relevance score?

Comment: Oh, I thought you had a matching algorithm in mind already, and just wanted to know how to extract the values and sort them using JavaScript.  What kind of matching do you require?  Simple text similarity?

Comment: Yes, searching text fields for matches or partial matches. Thanks.

Comment: A simple matching process, without taking relevance into account: http://jsfiddle.net/aeDrx/